# Haneke - hnk_setImageFromURL

Tags: swift2, haneke

I tried hnk_setImageFromURL but it says "Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'hnk_setImageFromURL'.

I have imported the Haneke.xcodeproj manually. On top of the class there is 'import Haneke'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project under 'Build Settings' then Architectures, I needed to change the 'Build Active Architectures Only' setting to 'YES' then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's more because you set it like that:
`imgCover?.image.hnk_setImageFromURL(image)`
Instead of
`imgCover?.hnk_setImageFromURL(image)`